# NSTimer selector is not getting called

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have following code written to run `NSTimer`. But the NSTimer selector is not getting called.

.h file

```
@interface XViewController : UIViewController {
   NSTimer *repeatServerRequest;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *repeatServerRequest;

- (void)checkForMinimunOnetimePinEntry;
- (void) initializeTimer;
- (void)stopTimer;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize repeatServerRequest;

- (void)checkForMinimunOnetimePinEntry {
   // some code
}

- (void) initializeTimer {
    repeatServerRequest = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0
                                    target:self
                                    selector:@selector(checkForMinimunOnetimePinEntry)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void)stopTimer {
    [repeatServerRequest invalidate];
    [repeatServerRequest release];
    repeatServerRequest = nil;

//    [self.repeatServerRequest invalidate];
//    [self.repeatServerRequest release];
//    self.repeatServerRequest = nil;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Also answer me which one is right to use: self.repeatServerRequest or simply repeatServerRequest??**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you called initializeTimer?  Confirm with a breakpoint there.  As for the 2nd part all you need is the invalidate and set to nil if you use the property accessor (the property itself will handle the memory management for you).  If you do it the way you did it, it's correct but it's better to stick to the property methods (outside of init and dealloc of course)

Comment: Yes I used that only using this stmt `[self initializeTimer];`

Comment: are you sure you are waiting enough, since the timer is set to 15 seconds, did you ever wait 15 seconds?

Comment: yes.. I did wait. Now let me tell you I call this method on `UITabViewController` delegate method `didSelectViewController`. I trigger timer when specific **X Tab** is tapped. & also I `stopTimer` the timer on `applicationWillResignActive` **Surprisingly when I leave the X Tab & come back then timer gets triggered & starts running.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign timer to a class field, not a property.

To make this code working, just put `self.` before `repeatServerRequest =`.

When you use `self.repeatServerRequest`, compiler invokes `[self setRepeatServerRequest:...]` and retains autoreleased timer.

Comment: I tried this also but NO SUCCESS :-(   I dont need to use `fire` message to trigger the `NSTimer`??

Comment: App is now crashing on the stmt `[self.repeatServerRequest invalidate];` and `[self.repeatServerRequest release];`

Comment: No, you don't need to use fire because you called *scheduled* timer.  That means that it will automatically start itself.  Also, since it is repeating, it is guaranteed to remain valid until you cancel it because it will be retained by the run loop it is in (so autorelease is not the problem).

Comment: As a side not, don't call release directly on your properties (note my comment above).  It will cause an overrelease.

Comment: @borrrden OK Thanks alot for ur guidance. Now let me tell you I call this method on `UITabViewController` delegate method `didSelectViewController`. I trigger timer when specific **X Tab** is tapped. & also I stopTimer the timer on `applicationWillResignActive`. **Surprisingly when I leave the X Tab & come back then timer gets triggered & starts running.**

Comment: That method will only be called "in response to user taps in the tab bar and is not called when your code changes the tab bar contents programmatically." (from the UITabBarControllerDelegate docs).  So if it is your initial tab, or you didn't get there as the result of a tap, then your timer will not start.

Comment: An NSTime needs to be added to a run loop before it begins running. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184081/the-selector-of-my-nstimer-does-not-run-why?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an init method for your class ? Perhaps you didn't put it in your code but I prefer to ask ...

Comment: hey can u just look for my comments on question? it may help u as i dont have init to call it