# How to update view from custom Timer object

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nstimer

I'm building an app with a timer in it, and I've created a custom class, Timer, which is a wrapper around the NSTimer class.  It has a property called remainingTime which is periodically updated as the timer is running.

My view controller, TimerVC, instantiates a Timer object, and needs to update its view based on timer.remainingTime.  How do I achieve this?

I believe I should be using a delegate here, but I don't know how it would work.  Which class should implement the delegate method?

Or maybe my approach is all wrong?

Edit:  The reason I'm not using NSTimer inside of TimerVC is because I want to abstract it for re-use, and also decouple it from the view.

Here is my code for my Timer class:

```
#import "Timer.h"

#define SECONDS_INTERVAL 1

@interface Timer()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@property NSInteger seconds;
@property NSInteger secondsRemaining;

@end


@implementation Timer
- (Timer *)initWithSeconds:(NSInteger)seconds {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.seconds = seconds;
        self.secondsRemaining = self.seconds;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start {
    self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:SECONDS_INTERVAL target:self selector:@selector(updateSecondsRemaining) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)pause {

}

- (void)stop {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}

- (void)reset {
    [self stop];
    self.secondsRemaining = self.seconds;
}

- (void)updateSecondsRemaining {
    self.secondsRemaining = self.secondsRemaining - SECONDS_INTERVAL;

    if (self.secondsRemaining == 0) {
        [self timerFinished];
    }
}

- (void)timerFinished {
    [self reset];
}
```

Comment: It's not clear why you're creating a custom class rather than putting your timer in TimerVC. Do you want to do this view update once when the timer reaches a certain value, or multiple times, or at a specific time in the future? A little more detail about your problem would be helpful.

Comment: Please post the code of your Timer class. What you are trying to get is a timer that informs of its progress before firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically your view's view controller would implment that delegate.

Define the protocol in a .h file. Let's say its name is `CustomTimerDelegate`. Add an `id <CustomTimerDelegate> timerDelegate;` property to your custom timer. Set the delegate when the custom timer was created. The protocol contains one method at least that is invoked by the timer every time when the view controller should update its view. The view conroller implements the protocol. In its .h file you add `<CustomTimerDelegate>` to the `@interface` statement. In its .m file you implement the method that is called though the protocol.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ok, I think I see.  My VC implements the protocol method, and my Timer class calls that method.

Comment: BTW, if anyone else comes across this, when using NSTimer like how I'm doing it, there are thread/loop issues, which can be resolved with this code when you instantiate it:  `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`.  From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8184194/1672161

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would need to write a custom timer for that.

In your TimerVC use this to create a new timer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
        target:self
        selector:@selector(timerCallback:)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:YES];
```

This will call the `timerCallback:` method every second. In this method you can update your remaining time property and you can also update your view.

Answer (score 1):

Just completing Hermann Klecker answer.. please don't forget that on your timer class the property should be

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id <CustomTimerDelegate> delegate
```

This is.. a weak property to avoid memory leaks when having your VC holding the timer strongly and your timer holding the delegate (in this case the VC) strongly... they would be retained in memory even if VC gets dumped (because timer would have a strong pointer to it) causing VC to not deallocate, thus not making the Timer deallocate thus not making the VC deallocate... and so forth...

with weak you avoid this...